# Duplicating a row and modifying the duplicate as a macro or regex

Tags: regular-expression, macro

Given a file with multiple lines matching this pattern (apologies for the length!)

```
$this->execSQL('INSERT INTO `table_lowercase_and_underscores` (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`) VALUES (\'first-guuid-lowercase-numbers-hyphens\', \'guuid-lowercase-numbers-hyphens\', \'guuid-lowercase-numbers-hyphens\', 0, \'2018-04-09 03:58:59\', 0);');
```

I would like to visually select multiple of these lines and apply a macro or regex replacement to yield the following pattern below each target line:

```
$this->execSQL('DELETE FROM `table_lowercase_and_underscores` WHERE id =  \'first-guuid-lowercase-numbers-hyphens\';');
```

I know I can capture the first backtick contents with something like

```
s/`\([a-z_]*\)`
```

And could grab the first match of `\'something'\` into 2 capture groups, but how would I then get those into a new line following the first?

Would this be easier to tackle as a macro to duplicate the line and then replace a few parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done with just a `:s`:

```
:s/\v.{-}(`.{-}`).{-}(\\'.{-}\\').*/&\r$this->execSQL('DELETE FROM \1 WHERE id = \2;');/
```

The regex `\v.{-}(`.{-}`).{-}(\\'.{-}\\').*`:

- enables very magic (`\v`)
- uses [lazy matching](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#non-greedy) instead of greedy (`{-}`)
- matches the table name in the first group `` (`.{-}`) ``, and the first GUID in the second `(\\'.{-}\\')`, by virtue of lazy matching.
- covers the entire line.

So the replacement:

- replaces the line with itself, followed by a newline (`&\r`)
- and constructs the new query with the two groups.